what makes this edible powder wrap novel or non-obvious
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcIxN6ALj4c
Start at 4:34
https://patents.google.com/patent/US20230391522A1/en?oq=US-20230391522-A1
So consumable powder wrapped in edible ingredient already exist. Many vitamin supplement already does this.
So what makes wrapping protein powder in edible ingredients novel or non-obvious?

It is the publication of an application, not an issued patent. It may be in a time period when third parties can submit published documents showing lack of novelty or obviousness.
And, as in EricS’s answer people often look at a title, abstract or specification and think it’s not novel but don’t look at what is being claimed. And claims in an application are frequently narrowed in prosecution.

how are the third parties made aware of this patent application?

You could set an alert through Google patent search or other services. Once aware, there is a time window for free submission of publications that the examiner is required to check consider. https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/FAQ%20AIA%20Preissuance%20Submissions.pdf

@BearBileFarmingisTorture Also looking at the claims, they are pretty complicated. They aren’t just wrapping edible powder.
